# How to select from multiple tables when you have a join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a current query that gives me a table of user ids and counts, but I want that table to be more descriptive. This query works fine:

```
SELECT a.user_id, count(*) FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE <some condition>
    AND <some condition>
    AND b.account_created_at < a.account_created_at
GROUP BY a.user_id
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

However, I want to add fields to the output, and am having trouble doing so:

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.organization, b.first_name, b.last_name, b.alias, count(*) FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE <some condition>
    AND <some condition>
    AND b.account_created_at < a.account_created_at
GROUP BY a.user_id
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

But I get an error that says `b.organization must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

Basically, as output, I would like:

```
organization | first_name | last_name | alias | user_id | id_counts
```

where all but the last two columns come from `table_b`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need  the column not in aggregation function in group by

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.organization, b.first_name, b.last_name, b.alias, count(*) 
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE <some condition>
    AND <some condition>
    AND b.account_created_at < a.account_created_at
GROUP BY a.user_id, b.organization, b.first_name, b.last_name, b.alias
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

or add aggregation function for these columns

```
SELECT a.user_id, max(b.organization), max(b.first_name), max(b.last_name), max(b.alias), count(*) 
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE <some condition>
    AND <some condition>
    AND b.account_created_at < a.account_created_at
GROUP BY a.user_id, b.organization, b.first_name, b.last_name, b.alias
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: What does `max(b.organization)` mean? It's a max of a string (e.g. - StackOverflow)?

Comment: there is also max of a string  ..  anyway if the db engine require an aggregation function you must use one  of  the available  ..  .. In this case are fake aggreagtion  function  .. just for avoid the error for missing aggregation function  respected  the columns in group by

Comment: Okay and these will only return the organizations, first names, last names, and aliases (which are in table B) that are associated with the user id in table A, right?

Comment: yes   .. based  on the relation you have  in `FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.user_id = a.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

All the items in the select section other than count,should be in the group by section of the query as well.

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.organization, b.first_name, b.last_name, b.alias, count(*) FROM 
table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE <some condition>
AND <some condition>
AND b.account_created_at < a.account_created_at
GROUP BY a.user_id,b.organization, b.first_name, b.last_name, b.alias
ORDER BY count DESC
```